# Git Flow CLI Incompatible With GitHub Protected Branches

Tags: github, git-flow

Probably similar in some ways to [Github Protected Branches with GitFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651406/github-protected-branches-with-gitflow) which isn't answered.

Basically, if I enable protected branches and require things like status checks pass and PR's are approved by at least one reviewer I can't finish a feature using the [git flow CLI tooling](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) (which I find quite convenient). (note that I typically am squashing with `git flow feature finish -S` in case this is relevant)

Even though PR's are approved and meet criteria (not stale, all status checks passed, PR green etc) issuing a git flow feature finish will delete the feature branch locally and remotely (by default) and merge the PR into the local develop branch. If you then try to push develop to remote github refuses with things like:

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/develop.
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.
remote: error: 2 of 2 required status checks are expected.
```

I am not precisely sure what github isn't happy about, whether it's because the feature branch is deleted without being merged via their UI or because the state of the develop branch locally has now deviated from the one it remotely compared the PR against as the target branch of the merge. Either way it seems that using git flow style work flows without using the built in merge features of the github UI doesn't really work with protected branches).

Does anyone know of a way around this, perhaps I should not squash commits or should favour a rebase over merge? Does anyone else use git flow with protected branches successfully?

Answer (score 0):

We ran in to the same problem when using the vanilla git CLI.

I received `remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.` when attempting to push `develop` (after having updated from `master`)

It seems github locks down all pushing when you ✅ **Require pull request reviews before merging** (which I guess makes sense—otherwise you could skip your reviews)

We only ran into this because we had also checked **Include administrators**

As our admins are the only ones needing to push straight to develop we've just disabled that setting. This may not be the case for you.

Comment: Looks like your linked question now has a similar answer to mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086070/2520131

Comment: We've actually ended up moving away from gitflow CLi for finishing features. We start features with gitflow CLI but now always merge  PR's via the github UI. This was the only way we could find to let the workflow work for our whole team (we actually want to force admins to behave the same as all other developers). Also, we found tools like pull reminders https://pullreminders.com/ couldn't work with metrics when closing features this way (because it tracks PR's based on them being "merged" rather than "closed" according to github. Closing via GitFlow CLI resulted in closed PR's, not merged.